# What would you call all-drum instrumental music?

Tags: drums, terminology

I'm trying to find the title for music containing all percussion instruments (pianos/xylophones not included) such as drum corps and marching band drum breakdowns. I'd basically like to listen to music completely consisting of drum beats. What would one call this genre? If I wanted to listen to this on Pandora, for instance, what would I put in the search field?

Comment: Well... Stomp is considered a musical.

Comment: A famous modernist piece that uses only non-pitched percussion is *Ionisation* by Varèse. Well, it has piano, but the players just beat on the strings inside, so I don't think that counts.

Comment: A term used often in marching bands is a drum cadence. While they technically can include pitched percussion, they very often do not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Percussion, by definition, includes pitched percussion. So it sounds like you're looking specifically for "non pitched percussion music".

Some descripting terms that come to mind might be **drum circle**, **drum line**, **rhythm music**, **street beats**, **african drumming**.

Comment: Look for "percussion ensemble".

Comment: @Wheat Percussion Ensemble instrumentation _usually_ includes pitched percussion instruments such as marimba, vibraphone, xylophone, tubular bells, orchestra bells, and timpani. You're right that instrumentations without those instruments still might be labeled "percussion ensemble," but that won't help to exclude the pitched instruments.

Comment: "atonal percussion ensemble"?

Comment: atonal music can still use pitched instruments - it just isn't based on a tonal centre or key.

Answer (score 5):

See also percussion ensemble and drum troupe.

Answer (score 4):

I would just call it "Percussion music". Google does seem to return results for that.

Answer (score 3):

I was wondering the same thing a while ago. So I am adding some recommendations for people searching this type of music

-Steve Reich- He does various types of "experimental, minimal" music, but anything titled "Drumming"  is percussion only

-John Cage Percussion works

-Xenakis- Percussion works

Comment: In Steve Reich's case, also "clapping", and in John Cage's call also "prepared piano", which were initially invented with percussion in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I would start on Pandora searching for an actual percussion ensemble. A good start would be So Percussion. Then continue to like their music.